# Is my proof of $|x|-|y| \le |x-y|$ correct?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

So I just started Spivak's Calculus and I am working my way through the problem set. However, my proofs don't always aline with Spivaks and I would like to know if they are still acceptable proofs.

Note this is my first time reading a math book like this and I haven't written proofs before.

Here it goes

**Prove that: $|x|-|y| \le |x-y|$**

$(|x|-|y|)^2 \le (|x-y|)^2$

$|x|^2-2|x||y|+|y^2| \le x^2 + y^2 - 2xy $

$x^2-2|x||y|+y^2 \le x^2 + y^2 - 2xy $

$ -2|x||y| \le 2xy $

And we know the last part is true, so $|x|-|y| \le |x-y|$

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: $-2 \leq 1$ but $(-2)^2 > 1^2$.

Comment: Simply use triangle inequality $$|x| = |x-y+y| \le |x-y|+|y|$$

Comment: Purely about your proof writing: it is okay to go this route in order to find a way out, but if you have found this way then you better turn things around to end up (not to start) with the statement that must be proven. Alternatively you can maintain the order of rank and start with saying something as: "the following statements are equivalent".

Comment: Apparently you want to "start" from the last line in the calculations, $\;-2|x||y|\le2xy\;$ , and from there on going up until what we want to prove. But then this isn't invalid in my opinion, precisele because of solitary's example in his comments above, and because of this you cannot  go from the second line to the first one (the first one = begins with "Prove that:...") , as when you have squares in the real numbers the difference between negative and positive (or elements and their additive inverses) disappears.

Comment: @Crostul I understand how that works, but I didn't think of it myself and I wanted to see if my solution worked. Very helpful though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before the first line of your proof just write this text.

If $|x| \lt |y|$ then the inequality is trivially true (since the RHS is $\ge 0$).
If $|x| \ge |y|$, then it suffices to prove that the same inequality holds for the squares of the two sides.

And then you proceed with your proof.
Between the lines of your proof write equivalence signs.

Otherwise it's not clear if you knew this and considered it too trivial
to mention, or you simply overlooked it and you're not aware of it.

Comment: This answer is perfect. I understand that and I did assume it too trivial. I also now know that I should write proofs in the other direction. Thanks for the help. Clears a lot up.

Comment: I think writing them in this direction is also OK as long as you indicate there's equivalence between any 2 consecutive lines. But writing them in the other direction increases the readability.

Comment: Nice and short answer +1

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't write proofs in this direction.

Start what what you know, then continue.

For example: \begin{align*} |xy| &\geq xy \\ |x||y| &\geq xy \\ -2|x||y| &\leq -2xy \\ x^2-2|x||y|+y^2 &\leq x^2-2xy+y^2 \\ |x|^2-2|x||y|+|y|^2 &\leq x^2-2xy+y^2 \\ (|x|-|y|)^2 &\leq (x-y)^2  \\ (|x|-|y|)^2 &\leq (|x-y|)^2 \end{align*}

However, we now reach an problem when we try to write your last step, because we can't take the square root of inequalities. To fix this, note that we may take the square root of inequalities if we know that  $|x|-|y|\geq0$ and $|x-y|\geq0$.  The latter is true by definition, and if the former isn't true, then we have $|x|-|y|\leq0\leq|x-y|$.

Also note that I fixed a minus sign in this writeup, because from the next to last line to the last line, you are making a sign error: you went form $-2|x||y| \leq 2xy$ to $x^2-2|x||y|+y^2 \leq x^2-2xy+y^2$, but then you change the sign of $2xy$, while you don't change the other signs. Fortunately it is easy to fix.

Comment: Nice answer. +1